# How to send and receive image file on localhost using curl PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send a image file from one PHP script to another PHP script.

Here is the sending code

```
<?php

    $url = "http://localhost/profiles/CurlPostFileRESPONSE.php"; 
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];



    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $finfo = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
    // var_dump($finfo);
    $cfile = new CURLFile($filename,$finfo,basename($filename));    
    // echo $cfile->postname;
    $data = array( "filedata" => $cfile, "filename" => $cfile->postname);

    if ($filedata != '')
    {
        $headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"); // cURL headers for file uploading

        $ch = curl_init();


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $filesize);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
    }


    // echo $response;
    ?>
```

And here is the receiving code:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_FILES);
    // echo $_POST['filedata'];
    // var_dump($_POST);
    ?>
```

I am getting this response instead of image

```
array (size=3)
  'name' => string 'signout.png' (length=11)
  'mime' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  'postname' => string 'signout.png' (length=11)
array (size=0)
  empty
```

I want the response to be an image or at least $_FILES or something so that i can use the image accordingly.